# Logging on as another user - Instagram OAuth

Tags: browser, authentication, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I am building a web application which makes use of the Instagram API. I use Instagram OAuth as a sign in to the application.

Currently my logout feature only invalidates the session, which works well for a logout. However, I run into another issue which is more closely related to browsers. Only one user, from one browser, can log in to the application. Meaning, I sign in to the app using Instagram OAuth, and each consecutive sign in will be authorized only to that user.

Is it possible to implement an Instagram OAuth login as another user? Setting up a kind of "remember me" feature? I do not see anything from the Instagram API to achieve this, so maybe I can do so with javascript? Or did I not sift through the Instagram API well enough?

So far the only solution I see is to implement a username and password for  my web application, and only then having instagram OAuth grant access. However, this defeats one of my development goals, which is a one click sign on (after the initial OAuth). I could put some more work into that one click sign in, but that leads to an intial stage of 2 logins (still not the worst).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opening `https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/` will log out of Instagram.

you can have a logout button and open the above url in hidden iframe, that will logout of instagram

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Instagram supports this, but OIDC defines a special parameter "prompt=login" which forces login to be displayed even for authenticated users or "prompt=select_account" which forces an account-selection dialog to be presented.

See Chapter 3.1.2.1 of http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

Comment: good thinking, but it's not supported for Instagram. I'll have to keep this in mind for future endeavors though!